# Google API - Auth server to server

Tags: php, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-php-client, google-workspace

I need a service to manipulate emails in a gmail account within a project developed in PHP Symfony...

I found this example : https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/main/docs/oauth-server.md
But more confusing than helping...

I wrote this code :

src/Service/Gmail.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Service;

use Google\Client;


class Gmail
{
    private \Google\Service\Gmail $api;


    private function getGoogleClient(): Client
    {
        $credentialsPath = getenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS');
        if (empty($credentialsPath)) {
            throw new \Exception('You need to set env var GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS');
        }

        if (!file_exists($credentialsPath)) {
            throw new \Exception('Credentials file path ' . getenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS') . ' set in GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS does not exist');
        }

        $client = new Client();
        $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
        return $client;
    }

    private function getApi(): \Google\Service\Gmail
    {
        if (!isset($this->api)) {
            $this->api = new \Google\Service\Gmail($this->getGoogleClient());
        }

        return $this->api;
    }

    public function getUserMessages($userId): \Google\Service\Gmail\ListMessagesResponse
    {
        return $this->getApi()->users_messages->listUsersMessages($userId);
    }
}
```

Then I followed the steps described in Google Workspace for developers :

1. Create a new project : https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-project?hl=en
2. Enable Gmail API : https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/enable-apis?hl=en
3. Create credentials for web application server-side : https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials?hl=en

But at this point I have no idea what type of credentials I need : "OAuth client ID" or a "Service account" ??? If I choose "Oauth client ID" I suppose I have to use the application type "Web application" with server side url ? Or do I choose "Service account" ?

With service account I got this error :

```
In REST.php line 134:
                                                                                                                                                                                        
  {                                                                                                                                                                                     
    "error": {                                                                                                                                                                          
      "code": 401,                                                                                                                                                                      
      "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.  
  google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",                                                                                                                                 
      "errors": [                                                                                                                                                                       
        {                                                                                                                                                                               
          "message": "Login Required.",                                                                                                                                                 
          "domain": "global",                                                                                                                                                           
          "reason": "required",                                                                                                                                                         
          "location": "Authorization",                                                                                                                                                  
          "locationType": "header"                                                                                                                                                      
        }                                                                                                                                                                               
      ],                                                                                                                                                                                
      "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",                                                                                                                                                      
      "details": [                                                                                                                                                                      
        {                                                                                                                                                                               
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",                                                                                                                          
          "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",                                                                                                                                              
          "domain": "googleapis.com",                                                                                                                                                   
          "metadata": {                                                                                                                                                                 
            "service": "gmail.googleapis.com",                                                                                                                                          
            "method": "caribou.api.proto.MailboxService.ListMessages"                                                                                                                   
          }                                                                                                                                                                             
        }                                                                                                                                                                               
      ]                                                                                                                                                                                 
    }                                                                                                                                                                                   
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not proeprly authorized your service account to delegate to a user on your domain.

```
require_once('../../vendor/autoload.php');

// Some user within your workspace domain
$user_to_impersonate = "your@domain.com";

$sender = $user_to_impersonate;
$to = 'another@domain.com';
$subject = 'Hello';
$messageText = 'How are you doing?';

// The path to your service account credentials goes here.
putenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=credentials.json");
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setSubject($sender);
$client->setApplicationName("Quickstart");
$client->setScopes(["https://mail.google.com/"]);
$service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer... One step forward !

Now I have the error `Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.` with the "service account" credential or error `json key is missing the type field` with oauth server-side. Any idea why ?

For the "service account" error I found in stackoverflow a solution you gave about "domain-wide delegation" but I don't have workspace account :/

Comment: you need to create service account credentials you don't need an API key

Comment: I'm not using API key, I tried with the 2 other credentials methods : the service account and oauth server-side credentials...
Like I said, with service account, I have the following error : `Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested`

Comment: You have not properly configured [domain wide deligation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/delegation)  the service account needs to be authorized by your workspace admin.